# Calling mock method instead of real method with Mockito

Tags: junit, mocking, mockito

I have a method which needs to be called instead of the real method.
Instead I get an exception. Can somebody please help me with right way to call the alternate method through mockito ?

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
2 matchers expected, 4 recorded.
This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));




    //Code starts here
class A{
   public realMethod(String s, Foo f){

   }
}

class B {
    public mockMethod(String s, Foo f) {

    }
}

class UnitTestClass{
    ClassA mock = new ClassA();
    mock.when(realMethod(any(String.class), any(Foo.class))).thenReturn(mockMethod(any(String.class),any(Foo.class));
}
```

Comment: @GhostCat sorry for the delay!

Comment: you can also use thenAnswer to forward arguments and set the return dynamically. Look at the answers to this [entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47534082/how-to-pass-argument-to-return-method-in-mockito).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting mocking wrong.

Here:

```
thenReturn(mockMethod(any(String.class),any(Foo.class));
```

That simply doesn't make **sense**.

Mocking works like this:

1. you create a mock object of some class, like `A mock = mock(A.class)`
2. you specify **interactions** on that mock object

Your code implies that you think that these specifications are working like "normal" code - but they do **not**!

What you want to do: **when** some object is called with certain parameters, **then** return the result of *another* method call.

Like in:

```
when(a.foo(x, y)).thenReturn(b.bar(x, y))
```

That is what *want* you intend to do. But thing is: it isn't that easy. You can't use the `any()` matcher in thee **thenReturn** part in order to "provide" the arguments that were passed in the `when()` call before! It is that simply.

**Mocking** should be within a specific unit test to get a **specific** result.

Meaning: you are not writing an ordinary program where it would make *any* sense to "forward" parameters to another call. In other words; your code should more look like:

```
when(mock.realMethod("a", someSpecificFoo)).thenReturn(mockMethod("a", someSpecificFoo))
```

That is the **only** thing possible here.

Beyond that, you might want to look into a Mockito [enter link description here](http://www.baeldung.com/mockito-spy) instead.

Long story short: it simply looks like you don't understand how to use mocking frameworks. I suggest that you step back and read/work various tutorials. This is not something you learn by trial and error.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Appreciate your feedback.. I agree I don't understand and this is first time I'm putting my hands into this.

Comment: That's fine. You got it "good enough" to give a reasonable answer. In case you consider upvoting/accepting feel free to do that tomorrow, as I already hit the daily cap today.