# How to pass argument to return method in mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I would like to pass argument of method I mock to return value

Example:

```
when(mockedObject.printEntries(anyLong()).thenReturn("%d entries");
```

Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to take advantage of the the `thenAnswer` feature:

```
Answer<String> answer = new Answer<String>() {
    public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        Long long = invocation.getArgumentAt(0, Long.class);
        return long + " entries";
    }
};


when(mockedObject.printEntries(anyLong()).thenAnswer(answer);
```

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
    when(mockedObject.printEntries(anyLong()).thenAnswer(invocationOnMock -> {
        Long aLong = invocationOnMock.getArgumentAt(1, Long.class);
        return aLong + 2;
    });
```